# mysql if statement not working- getting syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting error near the if statement...don't know why

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if @a=0 then
  select @a' at line 1

```
set @a = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hi where x=33 and y=-4);
```

if @a = 0 then select @a;
end if;

Comment: "Getting syntax error" is not a problem description unless you also include the error message you're getting, so we know **what the error is**. You have that information right in front of you - there is absolutely no reason for you to fail to include it in your question.

Comment: updated with error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `if` like that as plain sql, but you can refactor it to a `insert into select ...` and apply the condition in the `where` clause:

```
insert into hi (x,y)
select * from (select '33', '-4') x
where @a = 0
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39853) of the select part

Comment: What does the x do at the end of the select statement ?

Comment: And the second select is a subquery right ? , but not sure what it's doing

Comment: The 'x' is an alias that names the result of the subquery query - effectively given the table of results a name do you can refer to it like it was a real table. It's required by SQL syntax, whether or not you refer to it. The inner subquery is required to allow a where clause to be used, because to have a "where" you must have a "from". However, you can have a "select" without a "from", so by using an inner query you can select constant values, then by wrapping it up as a table you can use apply a where.